# In MySQL, is there any way to actually do something with a regex match?

Tags: mysql, regex

The [REGEXP function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) only returns true or false, and [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) be used to replace strings either. Is there any way I can actually get the matching string itself, or at least its position?

Edit: Sorry, but this is not a duplicate to the replace question, it might well be that there is some way to access the regex match in another context.

Comment: Whatever you;re doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you please reopen the question? I had clearly cited the other question as an example only of what kind of things I'm looking for, there might be other ways to achieve what I want.

Comment: No. There's no way to get the match. There's also no apostrophe in "its" (when used as the possessive form of "it").

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can actually get the matching string itself,

No. Not in native MySQL.  (Why ask why not? There just isn't.)

There's a UDF offering it, which you can add to your server if you control your server.   http://www.mysqludf.org/

Comment: That looks indeed promising. I've done it with Java now, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`; perhaps that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, that would be it, but I can't switch systems for that. Weird though that MySQL has been unable to implement that for [almost ten years](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27389) now. I thought there might be a way to at least get at the matches, but it doesn't seem so.